# What is the solution to this graduate-level statistics problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, brownian-motion

I'm baffled as to how to explicitly solve this problem... I would normally just plug in problem-specific values and use Monte Carlo simulation to solve something complicated like this, but my coursework is asking for a general solution.

A rocket is launched from the Earth. Random forces cause the rocket to move left and right. In an interval of time t, the rocket is moved according to a normal distribution N(t), where it is equally likely to be moved left or right. There is an asteroid belt on the right side x miles away.
1. What is the probability that the rocket will move j miles to the left in a*t (where j is less than x and a<=1)?
2. What is the probability that the rocket will hit the asteroid belt and explode?
3. What is the probability that the rocket will move into the “danger zone” (beginning at y miles, where 0 is less than y is less than x) and then return to safety?
4. What is the probability that the rocket will move into the danger zone and then return to safety z times (without an asteroid belt being present)? With an asteroid belt being present?

I'm thinking that this could be beyond my somewhat obscure graduate textbook's content, so any recommendations to a more comprehensive and clear statistics/probability textbook that would lead to a solution to this kind of problem are welcome. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You need to clarify because a) Log-normal is supported only on non-negative reals b) It's mode is not at zero c) It depends on two parameters - not one.

Comment: Sorry, I actually added that to the problem to make it applicable to the stock market, but the original question was just normal distribution, thanks for the clarification.